# Change jQuery Accordion Size When Clicked

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Is this possible?

I have content that displays with different width size. Sometimes the content spans across the browser while some content spans a quarter of the browser. I want to set the accordion width size to something like 50% but expands to 100% when clicked to accomodate for the large content.

Right now having all of the accordion width set to 100% looks very awkward.

I am using the example found in this tutorial: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

By default the style sets the width to 100%. I had to do a wrapper class to override that style to 50% but again, when I expand an accordion with big content it doesn't display all of it so you'll have to side scroll to see it.

So currently my accordion function is this

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: "content"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: please share some code so we can help

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also:[Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I apologize. But I am using a very similar code to this jQuery example: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's a solution but I found another accordion style widget that lets me choose the size of the "header" but will expand to fit the content: [Always Keep One Section Open Using AngularUI Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577595/always-keep-one-section-open-using-angularui-collapse)

Answer (score 0):

without more info heres a potential solution to set all accordions to the window width...

```
$('.accordion').width($(window).width());
```