# Always Keep One Section Open Using AngularUI Collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

Does any one know how to modify the Angular UI to only keep one section open like the jQuery Accordion?

Here is the Plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/zv8D1QdDs55iJ47UJhtM?p=preview

Comment: There is a bootstrap ui project by the angular UI guys that has an accordion directive: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forked your plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/Cih5IeIe1m3ATBOPI61j?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function CollapseDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = [true, true, true];

  $scope.openThis = function(e)
  {
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.isCollapsed.length;i++)
      $scope.isCollapsed[i]=true;
    $scope.isCollapsed[e] = !$scope.isCollapsed[e];
  }
}
```

and the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="openThis(0)">Toggle collapse</button>
    <div collapse="isCollapsed[0]">
        <div class="well well-large">First content</div> 
    </div>

  <br/>

  <button class="btn" ng-click="openThis(1)">Toggle collapse</button>
  <div collapse="isCollapsed[1]">
        <div class="well well-large">Second content</div> 
    </div>

  <br/>

  <button class="btn"  ng-click="openThis(2)">Toggle collapse</button>
  <div collapse="isCollapsed[2]">
    <div class="well well-large">Third content</div> 
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answer from @shaunhusain. I have made a similar solution, but allows you to have certain expanded together or only one at a time. This is of course more hands on, meaning you have to define which to collapse and which to expand in a function with if statements...like this:

```
$scope.chartTableActive = "btnBoth";
$scope.chartCollapsed = false;
$scope.tableCollapsed = false;

$scope.chartTableToggleFunction = function () {
    if ($scope.chartTableActive == "btnBoth") {
        $scope.chartCollapsed = false;
        $scope.tableCollapsed = false;
    } else if ($scope.chartTableActive == "btnChart") {
        $scope.chartCollapsed = false;
        $scope.tableCollapsed = true;
    } else if ($scope.chartTableActive == "btnTable") {
        $scope.chartCollapsed = true;
        $scope.tableCollapsed = false;
    }
}
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/4kkpm/).

Comment: That looks awesome man. I might have to reference some of that later on when I try to improve my site.